# from package import * as _

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My project has a number of `click` functions that is imported in my entrypoint with:

```
import package.module as _
```

however I'm implementing a `plugins` folder that allows user-created code to hook into the same utility. `package/plugins/__init__.py` is dynamically populating its `__all__` so I can `from package.plugins import *`.

I don't particularly want all those names polluting my namespace, though, I'm only using the import for its side effects. Is there a way to `import * as _`?

Comment: For what it's worth I understand the security concerns in allowing arbitrary user code to run when my CLI launches. I'm not concerned by this issue.

Comment: If you don't want anything but side effects, what do you gain from the `*` at all? Call `__import__('package.plugins')`, discarding the result, and you're done; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__. That said, I don't see why you don't just use `import package.plugins`; it's just one name, after all, and a usefully-namespaced one.

Comment: ...to expand for clarity: The *only thing* the `*` in `import *` does is control which names are copied to your current namespace -- it doesn't change what is or isn't evaluated in any way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ultimately because `package.plugins` does nothing on its own. I suppose I could `for path in __all__: __import__(path)` in `package.plugins`, but the magic happens deeper than that.

Comment: There's a circular import issue I'll have to work through though, since `package.plugins` exposes one member that I want the user's plugins to know about. It doesn't have to, though, I can reorganize that to fix the import.

Comment: How are these items getting into `__all__` in `package.plugins`, if nothing there imports them (or introspects to list files and imports them in turn)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `pathlib` globbing. Akin to `__all__ = [str(module.with_suffix('')) for module in pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.glob("*.py")]` but handles more corner cases.

Comment: @AdamSmith FYI `setuptools` provides a mechanism for [Creating and discovering plugins](https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/). If you have a `setup.py` you are probably using setuptools anyway so why don't use that instead of a home-baked solution?

Comment: ...use that same glob result to invoke import apparatus, and there you are. But using upstream-supported tooling is of course the better approach.

Comment: @Bakuriu I hadn't even thought about using this, but it doesn't seem to support loading modules as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AdamSmith I don't understand your question. You can define that you will collect the plugins from entrypoint `yourpackage.plugins` and then follow the last example to load all such modules.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the contents of a module to pollute your program, you can just import the module:

```
import module
```

or import as:

```
import module as name
```

`import *` is meant for the times when you *don't* want the module to be in it's own namespace. Doing this:

```
from module import *
```

automatically puts everything from `module` into the scope the import is in (usually the global scope). `from module import *` is a special type of `from module import something`, which imports only the specified contents into your program.

Be aware that submodules can be imported the same way as normal modules, i.e. `import os.path as somemodule` is legal.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve my problem, since `module` is essentially just a wrapper in this case. All the *magic* happens inside the submodules (the user-defined code) that are only listed in `module`.

Comment: @AdamSmith you can use imports on submodules the same as normal modules, i.e. you can do `from os.path import *`.

Comment: David: that's exactly the code I'm trying to avoid using, as it pollutes my namespace. That's the purpose of the question.........

Comment: @AdamSmith that's what I meant to solve with my answer. You can import submodules the same as normal modules.

Comment: I'm not sure how any of that satisfies my use case, sorry. `from whatever_path import *` saturates my namespace with names I neither want nor need. `import whatever_path` may be the same if `whatever_path` is a module, but for a package it is functionally different.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `import *` for the side effects specific to `import *`... well that's kind of a weird thing to do, but you can use `__import__` with `fromlist=['*']` to perform those side effects without any namespace pollution:

```
__import__('package', fromlist=['*'])
```

This will autoload all submodules in a package's `__all__` list, unlike a plain `import package`.